# springSecurityFilterChain not catch foward

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-security

my web.xml is

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
```

and my controller return

> forward:/uss/umt/user/EgovUserManage.do

springSecurityFilterChain can't catch forward ?

Comment: Can you please show how servlet/filter mapping of your MVC framework?